# Wincount for rock/paper/scissor game does not increase after a win. Additionally, how can I make it so the code continually runs games after eachother

Tags: python

I just started to learn python a few days ago. I made this for practice but the win counter does not increase after a win. I would also like to make the games run continually one after another. Any help would be appreciated.

```
print("Welcome to Rock | Paper | Scissors")
player1_wincount = 0
player2_wincount = 0

x = input("Would you like to play a game?\n")
if x == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES" or "Yeah" or "yeah" or "Yup" or "yup" or "Yessir" or "yessir":
    x = 1
    player1_name = input("Player 1, please enter your name:\n")
    player1_age = input("Player 1, please enter your age:\n")
    player2_name = input("Player 2, please enter your name:\n")
    player2_age = input("Player 2, please enter your age:\n")
else: x = -1

while x > 0:
    round = 1
    print("Round", round)
    player1_selection = input("Player 1, please select from the following options:\n1:Rock\n2:Paper\n3:Scissors\n4:EXIT")
    player2_selection = input("Player 2, please select from the following options:\n1:Rock\n2:Paper\n3:Scissors\n4:EXIT")
    round + 1

if player1_selection == "1" and player2_selection == 1:
    print("Tie!")
elif player1_selection == "1" and player2_selection == 2:
    print("Player 2 Wins!")
    player2_wincount += 1
elif player1_selection == "1" and player2_selection == 3:
    print("Player 1 Wins")
    player1_wincount += 1
elif player1_selection == "2" and player2_selection == 1:
    print("Player 1 Wins!")
    player1_wincount += 1
elif player1_selection == "2" and player2_selection == 2:
    print("Tie!")
elif player1_selection == "2" and player2_selection == 3:
    print("Player 2 Wins!")
    player2_wincount += 1
elif player1_selection == "3" and player2_selection == 1:
    print("Player 2 Wins!")
    player2_wincount += 1
elif player1_selection == "3" and player2_selection == 2:
    print("Player 1 Wins!")
    player1_wincount += 1
elif player1_selection == "3" and player2_selection == 3:
    print("Tie!")
else:
    x = -1
    break

print (player1_name,"has", player1_wincount, "wins!\n", player2_name, "has", player2_wincount, "wins!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two small mistakes in your case, the indentation of your if-else statements, and placing quotes around player 2's selections.

```
print("Welcome to Rock | Paper | Scissors")
player1_wincount = 0
player2_wincount = 0

x = input("Would you like to play a game?\n")
if x == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES" or "Yeah" or "yeah" or "Yup" or "yup" or "Yessir" or "yessir":
    x = 1
    player1_name = input("Player 1, please enter your name:\n")
    player1_age = input("Player 1, please enter your age:\n")
    player2_name = input("Player 2, please enter your name:\n")
    player2_age = input("Player 2, please enter your age:\n")
else: x = -1

while x > 0:
    round = 1
    print("Round", round)
    player1_selection = input("Player 1, please select from the following options:\n1:Rock\n2:Paper\n3:Scissors\n4:EXIT")
    player2_selection = input("Player 2, please select from the following options:\n1:Rock\n2:Paper\n3:Scissors\n4:EXIT")
    round + 1
    if player1_selection == "1" and player2_selection == "1":
        print("Tie!")
    elif player1_selection == "1" and player2_selection == "2":
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
        player2_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == "1" and player2_selection == "3":
        print("Player 1 Wins")
        player1_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == "2" and player2_selection == "1":
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
        player1_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == "2" and player2_selection == "2":
        print("Tie!")
    elif player1_selection == "2" and player2_selection == "3":
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
        player2_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == "3" and player2_selection == "1":
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
        player2_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == "3" and player2_selection == "2":
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
        player1_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == "3" and player2_selection == "3":
        print("Tie!")
    else:
        x = -1
        break

print (player1_name,"has", player1_wincount, "wins!\n", player2_name, "has", player2_wincount, "wins!")
```

Additionally the code for this program can be more condensed using [for loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 0):

```html
print("Welcome to Rock | Paper | Scissors")
player1_wincount = 0
player2_wincount = 0
round = 1

x = input("Would you like to play a game?\n")
if x == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES" or "Yeah" or "yeah" or "Yup" or "yup" or "Yessir" or "yessir":
    a = 1 
    player1_name = input("Player 1, please enter your name:\n")
    # player1_age = input("Player 1, please enter your age:\n")
    player2_name = input("Player 2, please enter your name:\n")
    # player2_age = input("Player 2, please enter your age:\n")
else: 
    a = -1

while a > 0:
    print("Round", round)
    player1_selection = int(input("Player 1, please select from the following options:\n1:Rock\n2:Paper\n3:Scissors\n4:EXIT\n"))
    player2_selection = int(input("Player 2, please select from the following options:\n1:Rock\n2:Paper\n3:Scissors\n4:EXIT\n"))
    
    if player1_selection == 1 and player2_selection == 1:
        print("Tie!")
    elif player1_selection == 1 and player2_selection == 2:
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
        player2_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == 1 and player2_selection == 3:
        print("Player 1 Wins")
        player1_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == 2 and player2_selection == 1:
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
        player1_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == 2 and player2_selection == 2:
        print("Tie!")
    elif player1_selection == 2 and player2_selection == 3:
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
        player2_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == 3 and player2_selection == 1:
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
        player2_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == 3 and player2_selection == 2:
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
        player1_wincount += 1
    elif player1_selection == 3 and player2_selection == 3:
        print("Tie!")
    else:
        a = -1
        break
    round += 1 
    

print (player1_name,"has", player1_wincount, "wins!\n", player2_name, "has", player2_wincount, "wins!")
```

There were a few mistakes in the code, well done for your project considering its your first few days of coding though!

- First of all, all the if/elif/else conditions weren't indented into the while loop
- The conditions of the if/elif statements weren´t of the same type. This means that the player 1 selection was always checking for the string "1" and player 2 selection was checking for a number/integer. I changed the input type to int, you can do it the other way around though if you wish
- The round 1 had to be definded outside of the while loop as it got redefined as round 1 every time the loop restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I still don't understand why even if you say "no" to start the game it still starts? It seems that the variable "a" doesn't get set to -1 even if you decline to start the game.

Comment: Because you only check `if x == “Yes”` the rest of your if statement can be simply read as ` or “truthy value” or “truthy value”` a non empty string is truthy. You are wanting to compare `x` to each of those “yes” values that you accept, or more simply want to see if the value of `x` is in a list of acceptable affirmative values… like so: `if x.lower() in [“yes”, “y”, “yeah”, … ]:` notice I also converted `x` to the lowercase version for minimal comparison options.